# Power BI - how can i count the occurrences of a value in a column?

Tags: count, powerbi, measure

I have researched this but not been able to get it working correctly.  I am new to Power BI. In the image (i censored user id's) you can see I highlighted order 0625140 because it should total to 3.  I've tried calculated column

```
Totals = CALCULATE( COUNT('Billing KPIs'[index])
, ALLEXCEPT('Billing KPIs', 'Billing KPIs'[order_id])) 
and quick measures and custom measure .

Totals =
   SUMX(
      VALUES(Data[User]), 
      CALCULATE(COUNT(Data[Group]))
   ) Based on previous posts but nothing has worked yet.  Please advise and thank you for your time.[Image of Data table][1]
```

[image]

Comment: You wants 1 row for 0625140 and count is 3? Or count 3 in each row for that order_id?

Comment: the latter, ie count 3 for each row for that order id

Comment: Your first Measure showing correct result as it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totals = CALCULATE( COUNT('Billing KPIs'[index])
, ALLEXCEPT('Billing KPIs', 'Billing KPIs'[order_id])) DID WORK MY APOLOGIES.